# При запуске команды npm run dev выдает ошибку

Tags: vue.js

[image]

При запуске команды npm run dev для шаблона webpack simple для vue.js выдает ошибку

> "cross-env" не является внутренней или внешней
>   командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего cross-env не установлен, выполните: npm i cross-env -g для глобальной установки.

Comment: Так себе идея. Лучше всё-таки не глобально ставить, хотя и да, помочь должно.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить и установить `cross-env` для разработки

```
npm i cross-env --save-dev
```

или для разработки и использования

```
npm i cross-env --save
```